# Limit at infinity of ratio of power series

Tags: real-analysis

The power series for $e^x$ is given by $\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Now let $g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n!}\log(n)$. Is it true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x) - \log(x)e^x}{e^x} = 0$?

This came up in my research. I have computer calculations estimating this ratio, and it appears to be true. A heuristic approach:

Inverting the Stirling approximation, we find that for large $k$, $e^k \approx \sqrt{2\pi k}\frac{k^k}{k!}$. Showing that if one takes the largest term (i.e. $\frac{k^k}{k!}$) in the power series for $e^k$, one needs to multiply it by $\sqrt{2\pi k}$ to obtain $e^k$. As $\log(n)$ grows sufficiently slowly, and the series for $g(k)$ has largest term given by $\log(k)\frac{k^k}{k!}$, a similar result would hopefully show that $g(k) \approx \sqrt{2\pi k}\frac{\log(k)k^k}{k!}$ which would show the result. However, I have not managed to make this rigorous.

Finally, I would like to apply similar reasoning to different series than $e^x$, for example to $h_r(x) = \sum_n \frac{x^{rn}}{n!^r}$, and now multiplying the coefficients by $\log(n)^s$, and comparing this with $\log(x)^sh_r(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a sketch of the answer, a more complete proof appears in my [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.10867). I would have liked to find a more elegant proof, but I guess this will do.

The first step is to show that for all the series $h_r(x) = \sum_n \frac{x^{rn}}{n!^r}$ that we can bound the tails of the series. More precisely, let $N_\pm = \lfloor x(1 \pm \epsilon) \rfloor$, where $\epsilon = x^{-\nu}$ with $\frac{1}{3} < \nu < \frac{1}{2}$. Then, we have:
$$\frac{\sum_{n = 0}^{N_-}\frac{x^{rn}}{n!^r}}{h_r(x)} = O(\exp(-x^\alpha))$$
for some $\alpha > 0$. Similarly:
$$\frac{\sum_{n = N_+}^{\infty}\frac{x^{rn}}{n!^r}}{h_r(x)} = O(\exp(-x^\alpha))$$
Then, use the fact that $\log(n) \approx \log(x)$ for $N_- < n < N_+$ to conclude the result.